# Plot circle displacement in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to create a plot that looks like the picture.

[Wave Particle Motions under Wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0gC5.png)

This is not homework, i'm trying to do this for experience.

I have the following parameters:

Plot the water particle motions under Trough (Lowest point on wave elevation profile) at water depths
from 0 to 100 meters in increments of 10 m below mean water line.

The wave profile varying over space is () = *cos(*x) at time = 0. Plot this wave profile first for one wave.

```
() = *cos(x) #at time = 0
```

Next compute vertical and horizontal particle displacements for different water depths of 0 to 100m

```
XDisp = -A * e**(k*z) * np.sin(-w*t)
YDisp = -A * e**(k*z) * np.cos(-w*t) # when x=0
```

You could use any x.
Motion magnitudes don’t change. Where z is depth below mean water level. All other parameters are as defined in earlier problems above.

Do not forget to shift the horizontally particle displacement to under trough and ‘z’ below water line for vertical particle displacement.

Here is my code, but im doing something wrong. I have the plot looking like the example but my circles are not right. I think it has to do with the x&y disp.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = 1  # Wave amplitude in meters
T = 10  # Time Period in secs
n_w = 1 # Number of waves
wavelength = 156  # Wavelength in meters

# Wave Number
k = (2 * np.pi) / wavelength
# Wave angular frequency
w = (2 * np.pi) / T

def XDisp(z,t):
    return -A * np.e**(k * z) * np.sin(-w * t)

def YDisp(z,t):
    return -A * np.e**(k * z) * np.cos(-w * t)

def wave_elevation(x):
    return A * np.cos(k * x)

t_list = np.array([0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0])*T

z = [0,-10,-20,-30,-40,-50,-60,-70,-80,-90,-100]
A_d = []
x_plot2 = []
for i in z:
    A_d.append(A * np.e**(k * i))
    x_plot2.append(wavelength/2)

x_plot = np.linspace(0,wavelength)
Y_plot = []
for i in x_plot:
    Y_plot.append(wave_elevation(i))

plt.plot(x_plot,Y_plot,'.-r')
plt.scatter(x_plot2,z,s= A_d, facecolors = 'none',edgecolors = 'b',marker='o',linewidth=2)
plt.xlabel('X (m)')
plt.ylabel("\u03B7 & Water Depth")
plt.title('Wave Particle Motions Under Wave')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid with provided information, I don't follow science part of the question, but if you have problem in marker size you can put an array of sizes as third argument of `plt.scatter`. I think this code may help you, although I change your code a little bit to make it simpler

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = 1  # Wave amplitude in meters
T = 10  # Time Period in secs
n_w = 1 # Number of waves
wavelength = 156  # Wavelength in meters
k = (2 * np.pi) / wavelength # Wave Number
w = (2 * np.pi) / T # Wave angular frequency

def wave_elevation(x):
    return A * np.cos(k * x)

A_d = [] # marker size
x2 = [] # for particle place on x axis which is wavelength/2
y2 = [] # for particle place on y axis
for i in range(0,100,10):
    x2.append(wavelength/2)
    y2.append(-i)
    A_d.append(15 * np.exp(-k * i)) # here I change A to 15
    
x = []
y = []
for i in range(0,wavelength):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(wave_elevation(i))
plt.plot(x,y,'red')
plt.scatter(x2,y2,A_d)
plt.ylim(-100, 10)
plt.xlabel('X (m)')
plt.ylabel("\u03B7 & Water Depth")
plt.title('Wave Particle Motions Under Wave')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: It didn't work correctly. it made the circles solid and the diameter of the top circle should be touching the line. that's why i need to use the XDisp & YDisp. But i don't know how.